# fpaq0.cpp is supposedly a "0-order" compressor. Why does it use a context then?

Tags: data-compression, encoding-scheme

In http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html#Section_32 Matt Mahoney states:

```
The simplest of these is the order 0 coder fpaq0.
```

in http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html#Section_41 he states:

```
An order 0 model uses no context.
```

but in http://mattmahoney.net/dc/fpaq0.cpp the Predictor (model) is defined with a context:

```
class Predictor {
  int cxt;  // Context: last 0-8 bits with a leading 1
  int ct[512][2];  // 0 and 1 counts in context cxt
public:
  Predictor(): cxt(1) {
    memset(ct, 0, sizeof(ct));
  }

  // Assume a stationary order 0 stream of 9-bit symbols
  int p() const {
    return 4096*(ct[cxt][1]+1)/(ct[cxt][0]+ct[cxt][1]+2);
  }

  void update(int y) {
    if (++ct[cxt][y] > 65534) {
      ct[cxt][0] >>= 1;
      ct[cxt][1] >>= 1;
    }
    if ((cxt+=cxt+y) >= 512)
      cxt=1;
  }
};
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matt Mahoney himself in an email:

"It is bytewise order 0, not bitwise. It models byte probabilities independently one bit at a time. The bit probabilities depend on previous bits."

Comment: Bravo for going straight to the source!